# SearchBar with webview isn't working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uisearchbar

I'm creating a Google search with a `UIWebView` and `UISearchBar`.

Here's the code from the .m file -

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController3

-(IBAction)Googlesearch:(id)sender {
    NSString *query = [googleBar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%@", query]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webview3 loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:webview3];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webview3];
}

@end
```

.h file -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController3 : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webview3;
    IBOutlet UISearchBar *googleBar;
}

-(IBAction)Googlesearch:(id)sender;

@end
```

Note: The IBactions on both files aren't connected (as I am unsure where to connect it to). But the webview/searchbar are connected to the iboutlets.

**How it's suppose to work:**

The webview is blank at first, input text in the searchbar, press "search", uiwebview loads Google with the search results of the query entered in the searchbar

**Problem/Question:**

When I run the app, the `UIWebView` doesn't load the Google search when I input something into the searchbar.

How do I fix this?

Comment: UIWebView load fine when you don't input something in the searchbar?

Comment: @anhtu it doesn't load at all because you must input something before it can load

Comment: When does it load? So what is the problem?

Comment: You have to connect IBAction. So it can go to `-(IBAction)Googlesearch:(id)sender`

Comment: @anhtu what do I connect it to?

Comment: connect with this function `-(IBAction)Googlesearch:(id)sender`. You should watch some video for using Interface Builder

Comment: @anhtu what do I connect the IBACTION to?

Comment: @PHP Web Dev 101 i have added an answer check.

Comment: Try Rajatp answer. Set delegate of UISearchBar by Interface Builder also. Just drop drag.

Comment: Write you code in to `viewDidLoad`  which you have written on the button action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the delegates of your `UISearchBar` object then this method will triggered

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
       NSString *query = [googleBar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%@", query]];
       NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
      [webview3 loadRequest:request];
      [self.view addSubview:webview3];
      [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webview3];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   googleBar.delegate = self;
}
```

Now write your code inside this method.

Comment: So all I do is add the code to my .m file (above the IBACTION)

Comment: have you set the delegate in your viewDidLoad method like googleBar.delegate = self